# How should I organize different style files (for global use) in Angular?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library

I'm struggling about this but I can't figure out what is the best or the right approach to do this.

We start a project with two folders under src, **app** and **assets**.

But I need to make some .scss files to configure some styles, and don't know where do I have to put these files organized for this project, for libs like:

- Bootstrap (I'm only importing grid, container and utils classes) ex: I created a bootstrap-utils.scss file
- Angular Material custom theming that I'll have to do later. ex: I created a dir theme/..dark..light/theme.scss
- And imagine *n* others libs that I may have to config some styles and etc. ex: Create a toast.scss

And of course, I don't want to put all these things directly into style.scss (under src/)
But I wonder how can I organize these type of files (just styles) in a correct and organized way.
I can just think about libraries (Angular ones) to put all this type of things, or maybe I just can create a folder into src/ like src/styles and put everything right there?

Something like this I think?

> lib/styles/src/lib/ [bootstrap, toast, custom-theme]

Or

> src/styles/ [bootstrap, toast, custom-theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plain CSS files that you import from libraries, you can either import them into your style sheets, or import them into you `angular.json` file

```scss
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

(The `~` is used to target node modules folder)

```json
{
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss", 
    "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
  ]
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to write your own style and add it to your style sheets, what I like to do is to create partials and put them in a defined folder. For instance, create a folder `styles` at the root and do this in `angular.json`

```json
{
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": ["styles"]
  },
}
```

Now, you can create your files in this folder, for instance like this :

```
styles
  _vars.scss
  _mixins.scss
  layout
    _cards.scss
```

You name them with a leading `_` to let SASS know that it is a partial, and should be only used, not compiled.

And **anywhere in your application**, you can use

```scss
@use "vars";
@use "layout/cards";

:host {
  color: vars.$blue;
}
```

Finally, to better isolate my styles, I also include mixins in files, for instance `_cards.scss`

```scss
@mixin core {
  app-card {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Then, in your `style.scss`

```scss
@use "layout/cards";

@include cards.core;
```

This ensures styles do not leak where I don't want them to.

Comment: hey MGX, thanks for your answer, I understand your point.
But for bootstrap example, I want to have all the classes ready to use, so... Should I use partials anyway? Right now I have this
"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": ["src/custom/bootstrap"]} (have bootstrap-utils.scss file)
and in my style.scss: @import 'bootstrap-utils';

Comment: I gave you my approach, there's no perfect one ! The one you're using seems great too, you have the same idea as me. I would still suggest using partials instead of importing them into your angular.json, si that you can reuse the classes if you need to (right now, you import them once and make them available to the whole application, even if you do not use them). Also, do not use `@import` but `@use`, as explained here : https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/

Comment: You're right, but I'll stick with this approach that I started, just organized the directories better because of you as clarified this for me, instead of creating libs or trying something similar, maybe I can learn other ways, but I don't have time for now. Thank you so much!
And about the `@use` instead `@import`, I'm already using the `@use`, but I forgot in this part, thanks.